# Loss function vs gradient updates in policy gradient methods

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the differences in notation used to describe the algorithms of Deep Q Networks (DQN), Policy gradient methods, and actor-critic methods.

For DQN, we talk in terms of loss function and it happens to look like MSE:
[image]
 For Policy gradient methods I see notation for loss functions that look like cross-entropy and I also see the policy gradient updates form:

[image]

For actor-critic methods, I have not been able to find a loss function. Everything is written in terms of update rule like the above with policy gradients. Why is this?

Comment: Well, update rules can also be derived for DQN and Policy Gradient, which generally look like this: $$\triangle\theta = \alpha * \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}; L = loss$$

Comment: What would you like to understand in these formulas mostly?